# Problema cargando imágenes con HTML y PHP

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Subir</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $token = "84329574329865";
    # definimos la carpeta destino
    $carpetaDestino="imagenes/data_".$token."/";
    # si hay algun archivo que subir
    if($_FILES["archivo"]["name"][0]){
        # recorremos todos los arhivos que se han subido
        for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["archivo"]["name"]);$i++){
            # si es un formato de imagen
            if($_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/jpeg" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/pjpeg" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/gif" || $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/png"){
                # si exsite la carpeta o se ha creado
                if(file_exists($carpetaDestino) || @mkdir($carpetaDestino)){
                    $origen=$_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                    $cambioNombre = rand(0,5000000)."_".$token;
                    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES["archivo"]['name'][$i]);
                    $extension = ".".$extension['extension'];
                    $archivoCompleto = $carpetaDestino.$cambioNombre.$extension;
                    # movemos el archivo
                    if ($_FILES["archivo"]["size"] >= 3000000){
                        if(is_file($archivoCompleto)){
                            $cambioNombre = rand(0,5000000)."_".$token;
                            $archivoCompleto = $carpetaDestino.$cambioNombre.$extension;
                        }
                        if(@move_uploaded_file($origen, $archivoCompleto)){
                            echo "El archivo numero ".($i+1)." se ha subido correctamente<br>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<br>No se ha podido mover el archivo: ".$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i];
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo "Archivo demasiado grande.";
                    }
                }else{
                    echo "<br>No se ha podido crear la carpeta";
                }
            }else{
                echo "<br>".$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i]." - Error al subir.";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "<br>No se ha subido ninguna imagen";
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="inscripcion">
        <input type="file" name="archivo[]" multiple="multiple">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"  class="trig">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema que tengo es que hay una imagen que no puedo subir, es JPG y dice que no la puede cargar.
Ahora la otra situacion, que por cierto me parece realmente extraña y no sé si solo me pasa a mí, no puedo cambiar al principio $carpetaDestino, o sea no puedo cambiar la palabra "imagenes" a lo que quiero, no me deja. No sube nada, y así si sube.

Comment: ¿Cuál de los mensajes de error recibes al subir la imagen?¿Has comprobado que no tenga un MIME type diferente a los especificados (independiente de la extensión que tenga)?

Comment: Cuando cambio en $carpetaDestino dice que no se ha podido crear la carpeta. Y cuando la imagen no sube, dice "Error al subir".

Comment: Si escribes el type en lugar del name de la imagen cuando falla, ¿qué valor aparece?

Comment: Creo que no te entiendo.

Comment: En lugar de poner `echo "<br>".$_FILES["archivo"]["name"][$i]." - Error al subir.";`, usa `echo "<br>".$_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]." - Error al subir.";` y comprueba que el MIME type es uno de los aceptados

Comment: Vale, ya reviso...

Comment: Da como resultado "  - Error al subir" no muestra el type. Pero en verdad es una imagen JPG y la imagen es de 3000 x 2143.

Comment: ¿Y rebasa el tamaño permitodo en el `php.ini`, por ejemplo, `upload_max_filesize = 2M`?

Comment: Que sea una imagen JPG no importa. Si no puede leer los datos de la imagen (y el type en concreto), siempre se va a ir por el `else` y mostrar el mensaje de error. Debes asegurarte de ciertas cosas: ¿se llega a cargar la imagen en el servidor?¿cómo de grande es?¿qué límites de tamaño tiene el servidor?¿Tiene el mime type correcto?

Comment: Bueno, la imagen sobrepasa el tamaño máximo. Pero siendo esa la causa del error almenos debería mostrar el tipo de imagen... No?

Comment: No, no debería. Porque al sobrepasar el tamaño máximo no se sube al servidor y no hay datos que comprobar. Haz que el tamaño máximo permitido sea más grande y prueba de nuevo

Comment: Ya encontré el problema para las carpetas, como tengo "Imagenes" y luego otra carpeta, supongo que mkdir no crea más de una carpeta al mismo tiempo, se debe crear una a una. Así me acaba de funcionar, no sé si esté mal optimizado...

Comment: Vale @AlvaroMontoro gracias, entonces el problema vino de php.ini. 
Ahora bien, en cuanto a las carpetas, qué raro.

Comment: Cambié el tamaño máximo para la subida de archivos desde el php.ini, pero igual la imagen no sube... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero lo primero, revisa si la carpeta creada tiene los permisos de escritura. Segundo, vamos colocando el código dentro de un `try catch` y ver que encontramos.

```
try {
    if(file_exists($carpetaDestino)){
    //Aqui va todo el codigo que tienes
    }
    else{
    @mkdir($carpetaDestino) 
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error encontrado brother, es este: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Por otro lado, hay algo raro: Si ya tienes la carpeta imágenes, lo que verificas es la subcarpeta creada, cierto? De ser así, tendrías que crear la carpeta individual y no toda la ruta.

```
data_".$token."/"
```

Evitando volver a sobre-escribir la carpeta padre, en este caso: imágenes.

Ahora, dejando el  presente código `PHP` al costado y viendo la configuración por parte del servidor, has visto que tan grande tiene el buffer de envío de archivos?

Comment: A qué te refieres con "buffer"?

Comment: un buffer es un espacio en memoria, si estas subiendo archivos grandes la memoria no aguanta y te lanza un error, para ello en el php.ini de la aplicación aumentamos el espacio, por ejemplo:
upload_max_filesize = 10M 
post_max_size = 10M

Comment: Lo de upload_max_filesize lo tengo en 5M. en post no he modificado nada.

Comment: qué error te sale?

Comment: El error lo tengo con una imagen en especifico, es imagen la he abierto en Photoshop y no hay ningun problema, no sé si importe, pero es la única imagen que no sube, es JPG.

Comment: pues esta en lo correcto, mira la linea siguiente a:  # si es un formato de imagen

Comment: Ahí está el tipo de archivo JPG

Comment: Agrega el filtro que te falta: $_FILES["archivo"]["type"][$i]=="image/jpg"

Comment: Omg, es increíble que lo haya olvidado

Answer (score 1):

El problema puede estar a la hora de crear la carpeta destino que no te la genere de manera recursiva o con permisos de escritura.

Si lees la documentación de [`mkdir`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mkdir.php), verás que hay algunos parámetros opcionales que puedes especificar.

Prueba con este if

```
if(file_exists($carpetaDestino) || @mkdir($carpetaDestino,0777,true)){
```

Comment: Alvaro Montoro, ya he especificado que son parámetros opcionales, que puede poner. El 0777 otorga permisos de Lectura, escritura y ejecucion, en lugar del 0777, puede usar 0666. El parametro true, sirve para crear los directorios de manera recursiva